# Check whether the image of any circle in $\Bbb C \backslash \{0\}$,is again a circle.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck with the following problem :

> Let  $f(z)=z+\frac 1 z$ for $z \in \Bbb C$ with $z \neq 0$.Then I have to check whether the following statement is true/fase?
>
> The image of any circle in $\Bbb C \backslash \{0\}$,is again a circle.

I tried by putting $z=re^{i \theta}$ [keeping in mind that $z$ can be on any circle with radius $r$] in $f(z)=z+\frac 1 z$ but could not make any conclusion from it.

Can someone explain?

Comment: Note that the circle you chose isn't in $\Bbb C\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Do I have to any point on the circle with center (apart from the origin) of the form $z-\alpha=re^{i \theta}$?

Comment: Nevermind, in my native language a circle in the whole disc, not just the border of the disc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Consider the unit circle $|z|=1$.  If we write this as $ \left\{ e^{i\theta} : 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \right\} $, then, its image under $z \mapsto z+\frac{1}{z} $ is readily seen to be
$$
\{ 2 \cos(\theta) : \theta \in [0,2\pi]\} = [-2,2],
$$

which is not a circle.  (Use $e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta} = 2\cos(\theta)$)

Comment: Indeed, the other circles centered at the origin should go to ellipses with foci at $\pm2$.